# Add multiple IP address ranges to an NSG security rule with array

Tags: arrays, azure, networking, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create 3 x NSGs in a copy loop (this works) and then add three different security rules that contain multiple IP address ranges per security rule. I can make it work when specifying just a single IP address space per rule. And I can specify multiple ranges directly in the ARM template when not using a parameter like below:

"sourceAddressPrefixes": [
"10.100.139.96/28",
"10.100.139.64/27"
],

But when I try to specify an array with multiple strings it doesn't work. So my question is: What should the parameter nsgPrefixes look like so that that multiple ranges can be added per security rule?

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "nsgNames": {
            "type": "array"
        },
        "nsgPrefixes": {
            "type": "array"
        }
    },    
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('nsgNames')[copyIndex()])]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": [
                   
                    {
                        "name": "DenyInternalSubnetInbound",
                        "properties": {
                            "protocol": "*",
                            "sourcePortRange": "*",
                            "destinationPortRange": "*",
                            "destinationAddressPrefix": "*",
                            "access": "Deny",
                            "priority": 4096,
                            "direction": "Inbound",
                            "sourcePortRanges": [],
                            "destinationPortRanges": [],
                            "sourceAddressPrefixes": [
                                "[concat(parameters('nsgPrefixes')[copyIndex()])]"
                            ],
                            "destinationAddressPrefixes": []
                        }
                    },
                    

                ]
            },
            "copy": {
            "name": "NSGcopy",
            "count": "[length(parameters('nsgNames'))]"
            }
        }    
    ]
        
}
```

---

### parameters file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "virtualNetworks_vnet_conn_weu_001_name": {
            "value": "vnet-conn-weu-001"
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "westeurope"
        },
        "nsgNames": {
            "value": [
                "nsg-snet-weu-001",
                "nsg-snet-weu-002",
                "nsg-snet-weu-003"
            ]
        },
        //this works:
        "nsgPrefixes": {
            "value": [
                "10.100.139.0/26",
                "10.100.139.64/27",
                "10.100.139.96/28"
            ]
        },
        //this does not work:
        "nsgPrefixes2": {
            "value": [
                "10.100.139.0/26", "10.100.139.64/27"
                "10.100.139.64/27", "10.100.139.96/28"
                "10.100.139.96/28", "10.100.139.0/26"
            ]
        },
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With some assistance some Microsoft, I got the answer:

The parameter nsgPrefixes should be configured as an array (within an array) and look like below (in the parameters file):

```
 "nsgPrefixes": {
            "value": [
                ["10.100.139.0/26", "10.100.139.64/27"],               
                ["10.100.139.64/27", "10.100.139.96/28"],
                ["10.100.139.96/28", "10.100.139.0/26"]
            ]
        }
```

In the template file I had two outer brackets [] too many, they have been removed, so it looks like below:

```
"sourceAddressPrefixes": 
    "[concat(parameters('nsgPrefixes')[copyIndex()])]",
```

That's it. This works and the IP address ranges are added to the security rule as expected.